# Linking 2nd row to different database table, in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

lets say I have the Users table, and the Team table.

In Rails, I know how to link the user_id column in the Team table to the Users table. But what if I have a second column I also want to link to the user's table, such as user_id2 (this essentially creates an order in the team table)?

Is there a solution, or something I don't know about to do what I'm trying? I also don't think the "has_many" is what I'm looking for, because user_id might be the team manager, and user_id2 might be the team captain, i.e. they have different roles affiliated with them, and order is important.

Thanks!

Edit: for my purposes, I also wouldn't need more than these two user relations. (i.e. cases for three wont be relevant)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) (look for Single Table Inheritance on that page) or [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Either would allow you to express your intent a bit more clearly, although there isn't enough information in your question for me to puzzle out which would fit best.

Give those a read and see whether they accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer steve, to be totally clear:
I want to select a row from the User's table in two separate fields of the Team table.

Answer (score 0):

First here is a way to do this in one direction (Team -> User), but it wouldn't work for the reverse direction, and there's a better option I'll get into afterwards. The first one assumes you have columns named `manager_id` and `captain_id` on the `teams` table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => ::User
  belongs_to :captain, :class_name => ::User
end
```

However, I'd be surprised if a Team only consisted of two Users (the manager and captain) - it's more likely that you'd want a join table to track all of the users' team memberships. That join table (called `team_memberships` in this example) could have a `role` column that holds the manager/captain info, as well as any other data you have. This way is a lot more flexible, and offers additional benefits, like being able to track historical team data if team members change over time, which they will.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :team_memberships

  def captain
    team_memberships.captain.first
  end

  def manager
    team_memberships.manager.first
  end
end

class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  # You'll need some database-level UNIQUE INDEXes here to make sure
  #   you don't get multiple captains / managers per team, and also 
  #   some validations to help with error messages.
  named_scope :captain, :conditions => {:role => "captain"}
  named_scope :manager, :conditions => {:role => "manager"}
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # depending on the rules about teams, maybe these should be has_many...
  has_one :team_membership  
  has_one :team, :through => :team_memberships
end
```

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for more details.

Comment: Hey trptcolin, I think I'll be trying this join table soon, but I dont understand why team_memberships.captain, and team_memberships.manager both have the .first? wouldn't that create an issue?

Comment: It's an artifact of using named_scope.  Leaving out the `.first` would get you a *collection* of 1 object, instead of just the 1 object (only 1 assuming that you added the UNIQUE INDEX, of course).  Read up on named_scopes for more info.